# Parameter Binding

Tags: powershell, binding, parameters, copy-item

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will move XML files of a certain age to a network drive to be archived. The script thus far:

```
$qaprocessedpath = "Y:\SFTPSHARE\SFTPYMSQ\YS42C1Processed"
$qabackup = “\\servername\S$\xmlbackup\qa"

$max_age_qa = "-1"
$curr_date = Get-Date
$del_date_q = $curr_date.AddDays($max_age_qa)

Get-ChildItem -include *.xml $qaprocessedpath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date_q } | Foreach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $qabackup} {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

This code leads to the following error:

```
    Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At Y:\SFTPSHARE\SFTPYMSP\XMLBackup.ps1:52 char:132
+ Get-ChildItem -include *.xml $qaprocessedpath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date_q } | Foreach-Object {Copy-Item -Path <<<<  $_.FullName -Destination $qabackup} {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Not sure where the issue is. I'm a novice scripter, so I'm sure it's something obvious...

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
Get-ChildItem -include *.xml $qaprocessedpath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date_q } | Foreach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $qabackup} {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

Why do you have two scriptblocks following the `Foreach-Object`?

Try separating the `copy-item` and `remove-item` with semicolons (in the same scriptblock) if you want them both to run.  As you wrote it, the two scriptblocks are getting bound to the `-Process` parameter (as usual) and the `-Begin` parameter.

Comment: Mike, thanks for this. I combined those two script blocks and separated each line with a semicolon. That cleared up the error and the script appears to execute, but when I check the source and destination directories, I find no files have actually moved. No error on the script this time, it's just not actually moving anything.